# Appending an element into xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

```xml
    <dictionary>
        <record>
          <word>hello</word>
          <meaning>xin chao</meaning>
        </record>
       <record>
         <word>bye</word>
         <meaning>tam biet</meaning>
       </record>
     </dictionary>
```

I wanna add another record at the end xml file 
here my code:

```java
    File inputFile = new File("Anh.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    docAV = (Document) dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
    Element records = docAV.getDocumentElement();
    Element newrecord = docAV.createElement("record");
    Element newword = docAV.createElement("word");
    newword.appendChild(docAV.createTextNode(word));
    newrecord.appendChild(newword);
    Element newmeaning = docAV.createElement("meaning");
    newword.appendChild(docAV.createTextNode(meaning));
    newrecord.appendChild(newmeaning);
    records.appendChild(newrecord);
```

when I build the project it didn't show any err but also didn't have the new record in xml file.
Thanks all.

Comment: You haven't included any code that writes the updated XML to a file.  If you want the XML file to be updated you will need to add some code that serializes your XML data back to the file.

Comment: omg! i forgot it. Thanks you so much :d